A way to make a browse for file dialog display with await async?
There is working code that opens a browse for file dialog in another question. I'd like to make this an await async call.
Here is the original question and it works in my tests.
I've added the snipper here for convenience:


// wait for window to load
window.addEventListener("load", windowLoad);

// open a dialog function
function openFileDialog (accept, multy = false, callback) { 
    var inputElement = document.createElement("input");
    inputElement.type = "file";
    inputElement.accept = accept; // Note Edge does not support this attribute
    if (multy) {
        inputElement.multiple = multy;
    }
    if (typeof callback === "function") {
         inputElement.addEventListener("change", callback);
    }
    inputElement.dispatchEvent(new MouseEvent("click")); 
}

// onload event
function windowLoad () {
    // add user click event to userbutton
    userButton.addEventListener("click", openDialogClick);
}

// userButton click event
function openDialogClick () {
    // open file dialog for text files
    openFileDialog(".txt,text/plain", true, fileDialogChanged);
}

// file dialog onchange event handler
function fileDialogChanged (event) {
    [...this.files].forEach(file => {
        var div = document.createElement("div");
        div.className = "fileList common";
        div.textContent = file.name;
        userSelectedFiles.appendChild(div);
    });
}
.common {
    font-family: sans-serif;
    padding: 2px;
    margin : 2px;
    border-radius: 4px;
 }
.fileList {
    background: #229;
    color: white;
}
#userButton {
    background: #999;
    color: #000;
    width: 8em;
    text-align: center;
    cursor: pointer;
}

#userButton:hover {
   background : #4A4;
   color : white;
}
<a id = "userButton" class = "common" title = "Click to open file selection dialog">Open file dialog</a>
<div id = "userSelectedFiles" class = "common"></div>



Here is what I have:
async browseForFile(acceptedTypes: string, multiple?: boolean): Promise<array> {
      var element = document.createElement("input");
      element.type = "file";
      element.accept = acceptedTypes;
      if (multiple) {
         element.multiple = multiple;
      }

      new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
         element.addEventListener("change", resolveCallback);
      })

      var resolveCallback = (event)=> {
         return event.currentTarget.files;
      }
      
      element.dispatchEvent(new MouseEvent("click")); 
   }

Suggested usage:
try {
   var files = await browseForFile("*.txt");
}
catch(error) {
   // no files selected
}

The answer I posted below seems to work if the user selects a file. But if they click cancel the promise is not rejected.

@Bergi I was getting errors making a browse for file dialog using async and await pattern. The question was how to do that without getting errors.  I could not even compile from Typescript because the code was not working.

Ah, then please post the error message in your question! And also add the TypeScript tag if that's where you have a problem!

@Bergi the code would not even compile. TSC gave can't return Promise types. But originally it was not even in a working Promise scope. But it's solved now. You can test and even review the answer. Do the snippet blocks actually support Typescript?

You need to return the promise so you can await the function.
And the promise needs to call resolve() with the value that you want returned by await.


function browseForFile(acceptedTypes, multiple) {
  var element = document.createElement("input");
  element.type = "file";
  element.accept = acceptedTypes;
  if (multiple) {
    element.multiple = multiple;
  }

  let p = new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    element.addEventListener("change", event => resolve(resolveCallback(event)));
  })

  var resolveCallback = (event) => {
    return event.currentTarget.files;
  }

  element.dispatchEvent(new MouseEvent("click"));
  return p;
}




That might work in theory. When I tried to run the snippet I would get error "Uncaught SyntaxError: missing ) after argument list". I got something else sort of running

I removed the typescript stuff and added the function keyword, and it parses now.

I got things working and put it into an answer. Do I need to remove the event listeners?

There's no need to remove the event listeners, since the input element goes away when the function is done.

This is working. I added comments. I haven't tested in all browsers.


// opens a file dialog and returns a list of files or null if user cancels
// must be called from inside the event bubble of a click event
async function browseForFile(acceptedTypes, multiple) {
      var element = document.createElement("input"); // create element
      element.type = "file"; // accept file type
      element.accept = acceptedTypes; // define types accepted - does not work on some browsers
      if (multiple) {
         element.multiple = multiple; // accept single or multiple files  
      }

      // inside of the promise add the event listeners
      // so that the promise can it can access the 
      // resolve and reject functions to resolve or reject
      // the promise
      var filePromise = new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
         
         // when user selects a file and clicks ok 
         // return the files property containing an array
         var resolveCallback = (event)=> {
            var input = event.currentTarget
            resolve(input.files);
         }
         
         // when user chooses cancel return null 
         var cancelCallback = (event)=> {
            resolve(null); 
         }

         element.addEventListener("change", resolveCallback);
         element.addEventListener("cancel", cancelCallback);
      });
      
      // show the dialog on click event
      element.dispatchEvent(new MouseEvent("click"));

      return filePromise; // return promise until it is resolved
   }
   
   // call the browseForFile async function from an 
   // async function 
   // the call must to await browseForFile must be in 
   // event bubble of a click event - check the console for errors
   // the method will return an array of files when 
   // the user selects a file or files and clicks ok
   // or return null if no user clicks cancel
   async function openUploadDialog(event) {
      try {
         var files = await browseForFile(".txt");
         console.log(files);
      }
      catch(error) {
         console.log(error)
      }
   }
   
   // get button and listen for click event
   var button = document.querySelector("#button");
   button.addEventListener("click", openUploadDialog);
<button id="button" title = "Click to open file selection dialog">Open file dialog</a>




"This seems to be working" does not explain the made changes to make it actually "work"

@RokoC.Buljan I'll add comments
